# How long should we wait for more details before closing a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Scenario:

1. Question is asked without enough detail
2. Community leaves comments on question for information required
3. OP never gives the required information

Example: [Basic search doesn't work but advanced search does](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/)

How long should we wait before closing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should close the question **immediately** and post a comment explaining how the user can get it reopened.

---

While a close may seem drastic, consider it to be more of a "probation" period instead of a permanent action. This helps in a couple of ways:

1. Requires the OP to edit the question to be answerable

   - If they do, mods/community can reopen question easily
   - If they don't, question is already closed
2. Community does not waste time with unanswerable questions

Also very important is a detailed comment. Explain the following:

1. More information is required to answer the question
2. That the user needs to edit the question
3. How to get the question reopened

See the "Question needs more information" in our [comment template](http://typewith.me/UVc3VJqtj5).

Comment: How will new users find this approach?

Comment: I'm torn between "Sudden Death" and "No mercy, no prisoners" as nicknames for this policy... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Kit for the large part, I think in some instances it isn't immediately obvious that necessary information is missing.

Requests for more information from the community are a good indicator (but not a guarantee) that a question needs more content. Being too quick to close a question could also scare the OP off for good.

I would say that 24 hours is long enough to see if a question needs closing, and it gives the OP a chance to come back and add content during the same time of day that they posted.

Unfortunately most of the time wasting would have been done by then, as it would have had its time on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the situation: OP (rep 1, joined the day of posting) question "I installed SP but it just crashes. Why?", then about five comments asking for clarification. One week elapses. No answer to comments from OP. OP has not interacted with the site since, and almost certainly posted this question and just moved on.

The result is a question with no useful information and which will remain unanswerred and help keep us in beta.

My suggestion: close after a week, delete after a month. You gotta be tough :-/

Comment: I think remarkably lenient in comparison to Kit's proposal. :)

Comment: I originally thought about the delay, but the current flagging system doesn't really support that which is why I suggested "Sudden Death". If the OP cares enough to reform his question, then IMO it is pretty easy to edit and then flag again. I think if we leave a comment each time explaining why, the user won't be afraid.

Comment: I think immediate close is a bit of a slap in the face. By all means adjust the time periods, but give the poster a chance to expand the question before opening the trapdoor. Even if there is a ladder to climb back up, I think most won't bother, because you are requiring them to grovel a little bit to the moderator.

Comment: After seeing similar behavior in other forums I'd say this is better, sure closing immediately is a way to be drastic and get attention not everyone is familiar with the system.  As we say in the US "innocent until proven guilty" so you have 7 days of innocence until your are judged guilty and jailed.

Comment: I'm all for a grace period but I think we still need some way to keep track of these "questionable" questions. :)